# SQLSTATE[HY093] error but arrays are the same length

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Having an issue where PDO is giving me the exception saying the parameter is undefined.  However, the two arrays I'm providing it with definitely have the same length and keys so what's wrong?

Below you can see the function, then the update query and then the array that's being sent.  52 is the length of each part, and below that is the exception text.

```
public function query($sql,$data,$read) {

    if (!($query = $this->connection->prepare($sql))) { exception(implode(' ',$query->errorInfo()),intval($query->errorCode())); } 
    if (!($query->execute($data))) { exception(implode(' ',$query->errorInfo()),intval($query->errorCode())); }

    if ($read) { $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $this->count_reads++; } else { $result = $query->rowCount(); $this->count_writes++; }       

    $query = null; return $result;    
}
```

UPDATE objects_servers SET `id` = `:id`, `info__enabled` = `:info__enabled`, `info__version` = `:info__version`, `info__title` = `:info__title`, `info__color` = `:info__color`, `info__contact` = `:info__contact`, `info__chunksize` = `:info__chunksize`, `info__downloadwait` = `:info__downloadwait`, `info__crypto__ciphers` = `:info__crypto__ciphers`, `info__crypto__salt-length` = `:info__crypto__salt-length`, `info__crypto__pbkdf2-algorithm` = `:info__crypto__pbkdf2-algorithm`, `info__crypto__pbkdf2-iterations` = `:info__crypto__pbkdf2-iterations`, `info__crypto__chunk-size` = `:info__crypto__chunk-size`, `info__email__hostname` = `:info__email__hostname`, `info__email__smtp-auth` = `:info__email__smtp-auth`, `info__email__auth-password` = `:info__email__auth-password`, `info__email__auth-username` = `:info__email__auth-username`, `info__email__from-address` = `:info__email__from-address`, `info__email__from-name` = `:info__email__from-name`, `info__email__port` = `:info__email__port`, `info__email__smtp-secure` = `:info__email__smtp-secure`, `info__email__bcc-address` = `:info__email__bcc-address`, `features__users__download-pages` = `:features__users__download-pages`, `features__users__file-encrypt` = `:features__users__file-encrypt`, `features__users__admin` = `:features__users__admin`, `features__server__email-validation` = `:features__server__email-validation`, `features__server__softlimit` = `:features__server__softlimit`, `features__server__publiclimit` = `:features__server__publiclimit`, `features__server__hourly-statistics` = `:features__server__hourly-statistics`, `features__server__actionlog` = `:features__server__actionlog`, `features__server__limit-alerts` = `:features__server__limit-alerts`, `features__server__sequential-contentfill` = `:features__server__sequential-contentfill`, `features__server__outgoing-email` = `:features__server__outgoing-email`, `features__server__multiple-accounts` = `:features__server__multiple-accounts`, `statistics__timed__#start` = `:statistics__timed__#start`, `statistics__timed__storage` += `:statistics__timed__storage`, `statistics__timed__bandwidth` += `:statistics__timed__bandwidth`, `statistics__timed__downloads` += `:statistics__timed__downloads`, `statistics__forever__storage` += `:statistics__forever__storage`, `statistics__forever__bandwidth` += `:statistics__forever__bandwidth`, `statistics__forever__downloads` += `:statistics__forever__downloads`, `limits__server__forever__storage` = `:limits__server__forever__storage`, `limits__server__timed__bandwidth` = `:limits__server__timed__bandwidth`, `limits__server__timed__downloads` = `:limits__server__timed__downloads`, `limits__server__timed-expire` = `:limits__server__timed-expire`, `limits__server__public-filecount` = `:limits__server__public-filecount`, `limits__server__public-filesize` = `:limits__server__public-filesize`, `limits__users__filesize` = `:limits__users__filesize`, `limits__users__filecount` = `:limits__users__filecount`, `limits__users__forever__storage` = `:limits__users__forever__storage`, `limits__users__timed__bandwidth` = `:limits__users__timed__bandwidth`, `limits__users__timed__downloads` = `:limits__users__timed__downloads` WHERE `id` = 'DjvMb938gkH867d3';

{"id":"DjvMb938gkH867d3","info__enabled":"1","info__version":"0.0.1","info__title":"Development","info__color":"#007127","info__contact":"yeeeup","info__chunksize":"2097152","info__downloadwait":"10","info__crypto__ciphers":"serpent:ctr","info__crypto__salt-length":"512","info__crypto__pbkdf2-algorithm":"sha512","info__crypto__pbkdf2-iterations":"5000","info__crypto__chunk-size":"1048576","info__email__hostname":"fun","info__email__smtp-auth":"1","info__email__auth-password":"nope","info__email__auth-username":"blah1","info__email__from-address":"blah2","info__email__from-name":"Person","info__email__port":"587","info__email__smtp-secure":"tls","info__email__bcc-address":"blah3","features__users__download-pages":"1","features__users__file-encrypt":"1","features__users__admin":"0","features__server__email-validation":"0","features__server__softlimit":"1","features__server__publiclimit":"0","features__server__hourly-statistics":"1","features__server__actionlog":"1","features__server__limit-alerts":"1","features__server__sequential-contentfill":"0","features__server__outgoing-email":"0","features__server__multiple-accounts":"1","statistics__timed__#start":null,"statistics__timed__storage":"0","statistics__timed__bandwidth":"0","statistics__timed__downloads":"0","statistics__forever__storage":"0","statistics__forever__bandwidth":"0","statistics__forever__downloads":"0","limits__server__forever__storage":null,"limits__server__timed__bandwidth":null,"limits__server__timed__downloads":null,"limits__server__timed-expire":null,"limits__server__public-filecount":null,"limits__server__public-filesize":null,"limits__users__filesize":null,"limits__users__filecount":null,"limits__users__forever__storage":null,"limits__users__timed__bandwidth":null,"limits__users__timed__downloads":null}

52 52

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in C:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\development\Andromeda\server\classes\database.class.inc.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\development\Andromeda\server\classes\database.class.inc.php(28): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\development\Andromeda\server\classes\server.class.inc.php(117): Database->query('UPDATE objects_...', Array, false) #2 C:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\development\Andromeda\index.php(71): Server->Save() #3 C:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\development\Andromeda\index.php(32): Andromeda->Run() #4 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\Apache24\htdocs\development\Andromeda\server\classes\database.class.inc.php on line 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many special characters (such a +, -, comma, ...) are not legal column names unless you enclose the column name in bactics:  `test__variable-hyphen`.

Otherwise, it looks too much like a subtract.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have narrowed it down - PDO only returns an error if one of the keys contains a hyphen like   :test__variable-hyphen   .  Why is that not allowed?

Comment: Because that is not distinguishable from the operator for the mathematical subtraction operation at that point …